# How to see the Check-In History of a particular user in TFS?

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs, history, checkin

How to see the **Check-In History of a particular** user in TFS (TFS-2008)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes. The easy way: download and install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) (it's free).

From the [attrice](http://www.attrice.info/) website:

[image]

Comment: It's good because you can also see items for users that are not active anymore!

Comment: A comment on how to find users using this tool would be useful, without that the user would have to spend some time researching, which would make Rolf's answer a much faster solution.

Comment: @developer747 According to their website, the screen looks like http://www.attrice.info/images/history_sk_screen.gif and it's easy to use as per the description on http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm
It takes almost same amount of words to show solution when you know, as to point the problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Probably, you've selected wrong version of Sidekicks (it MUST correspond to version of Visual Studio installed on your machine)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks, I'll try that. Remind me to tell you about a funny coincidence, sometime...

Answer (score 92):

[How to: Find a Changeset in Visual Studio 2010:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245461%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
In Source Control Explorer, on the File menu, point to Source Control, and then click Find Changesets.

For some reason newer versions of the article are in a different location.  Here are links to newer versions of the article:
[How to: Find a Changeset in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[How to: Find a Changeset in Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181408.aspx)

[image: Visual Studio 2013 menu location]

[image: Find Changesets]

Comment: Best answer so far. Works for VS2012 as well. Simple solution and doesn't require installing anything extra.

Comment: Works for VS2013 too, though there's an extra nested menu: File > Source Control > Find > Find Changeset ...

Comment: Works for 2015 as well. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: This should _definately_ be the answer.  While Attrice's Team Foundation Sidekicks provides many features, the quickest and easiest answer is to search the Change Sets in TFS itself.

Comment: Is there any option to export the data to excel?

Answer (score 15):

1. Open "Team Explorer" (Found in "View"-menu)
2. Find the team-project and expand "Team Members"
3. Right-click the team member and select "Show Checkin History".

But it is very strange that one cannot do this filtering directly, when viewing the entire history of a team-project.

Yet another alternative is to use the "Link to"-search within TFS WorkItem:

1. Open a TFS Workitem
2. Choose the "All Links"-tab
3. Press the "Link To"-button
4. In the new dialog set "Link Type" to "Changeset" and press "Browse..."-button.
5. Now you have a TFS search dialog, where one can specify username and other filtering

Comment: Is there such option for users that are not active anymore and that are not in the list because of that?

Comment: I don't see "Team Members" to expand

Comment: This is for the < 2012 team client

Comment: The "Team Members" is not in vs2010 premium

Comment: For a user in in VS >= 2012, the first three steps are the best answer on the page.  It's built in functionality and it works.  The wording is slightly different in VS 2013 "Show Checkin History" is now "Show Changesets", but that's a minor difference.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this by logging in to TFS and navigating to Code>Changesets

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAlUz.png)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation on how to do this using TFS Sidekicks.  A comment in the top voted answer asked for details, but I am unable to comment on posts so I added it as an answer.

Install TFS Sidekicks
Connect to your TFS server
Choose Tools | History Sidekick
Select User under User name pull down.
Select the branch or folder that you are interested in.

You will then see a list of changesets from that one user in the selected branch or folder.