# How to produce a report of every changeset for a particular user?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to produce a report that has every changeset for a particular user using TFS/Visual Studio 2015. I found a useful SO post ([How to see the Check-In History of a particular user in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599908/4183920)) that almost got me there.

I'm able to use 'Find Changesets' to list every changeset for a particular user just like I want to. The problem is that I'm unable to select all (or anything more than one at a time) to copy the results into a spreadsheet.

Is there a way to generate this type of report using Visual Studio 2015? If not with the IDE, are there recommended tools? I've seen [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) mentioned a few times but the site seems a bit out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Team Foundation Sidekicks is a good option. It would be easy to help you achieve your goal. Team Foundation Sidekicks is not out of date, instead, this tool is always up to date (You can see on its website that the version 6.0 supports VS/TFS 2015).

Under **History Sidekick**, select the file/folder/TeamProject that you want to check, then choose a User name, or just leave it blank. If you leave the User name blank, you'll get the changsets for all users. After that, you can save the list to a .csv file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I grabbed the latest version of TFSidekicks and it works very well for this purpose (along with some others!).